# How to add a second virtual IP address?

Tags: networking, server

How to add a second virtual IP address
I have this configuration: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - 140.55.210.187/25
            gateway4: 140.55.210.254
            match:
                macaddress: 81:0е:15:a9:cе:c5
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 1.1.1.1
                - 8.8.8.8
                search: []
            set-name: eth0
```

I want to add a virtual ip for example 192.168.1.1, how to do this? Thank you!